# Can this way auth user with role?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I don't want to use additional middleware like `connect-roles`, so is this sufficient enough to perform authorization?

```
function authWithRole(role) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        // Check login and role.
        if (req.isAuthenticated() &&
            _.indexOf(req.user.roles, role) > -1) {
            return next();
        } else {
            res.status(404).send('<h1>404 Not Found!</h1>');
        }
    }
}

router.all('/*', authWithRole("admin"));
```

Could anyone provide a simpler and more practical example for performing authorization?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can perform authorization this way.

This is as simple as it gets without using any extra modules.

You should refactor:

```
router.all('/*', authWithRole("admin"));
```

to:

```
router.all('*', authWithRole("admin"));
```